# The value of the local variable chaine2 is not used

Tags: java

I got this error message: `The value of the local variable chaine2 is  not used`.

The code:

```
package com.example.Projet_java;

public class MyFirstClass 
                         {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     { String chaine = new String("HELLO"),
      chaine2 = new String();
      chaine2 = chaine.toLowerCase();
     }
                                         }
                          }
```

I tried to follow the following thread 
[Java error "Value of local variable is not used"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062919/java-error-value-of-local-variable-is-not-used)
but without success.

Anybody knows how I could fix it?

Comment: it's an indicator provided by your IDE informing you that you might own a useless variable `chaine2`in this case. It's not a compilation error by the way.

Comment: How did you read that link and not understand your problem?

Comment: I have never seen more ridiculous brace placement, and, believe it or not, it is *not by accident*.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's a **warning**, not an **error**. This is the way compiler informs you thay you create variable which you never use. This variable is useless, so there is no point in creating it. You can just ignore this warning if you're learning Java, because it doesn't prevent your code to being compiled and execute. It's just a tip for you: "Hey, you have a variable you don'tuse! Maybe you've missed something?"

Comment: -1 for the advice to ignore warnings. They're telling you something you should pay attention to, especially while you're learning. They're trying to tell you that you're doing something the wrong way; just because it still compiles and runs doesn't make it safe to ignore. (They should never be ignored - they're called *warnings* and not *hints* for a reason.)

Comment: Well, you're an idealist :) In fact, sometimes you have to ignore compiler warnings - i.e. when reading serialized collection from ObjectInputStream. You can do nothing with 'unchecked cast' warning. In my opinion, it's common to ignore 'unused' warning when learning Java: you're creating lots of variables and such warning just doesn't matter.

Comment: And then you're making an *informed decision* about ignoring the warning. That's not the same as "you can ignore warnings" as a general statement, and giving that advice to an obvious beginner is absolutely terrible advice. (They're not called "suggestions" or "tips" - there's a reason the word selected to name them indicates potential danger.)

Comment: thank you for your suggestion,i really do appreciate and will keep that in mind.Sorry for my ignorance but could somebody write me down the correct code regarding the code above to get the string HELLO in lowercase?Even if I delete "chaine2 = new String();" i still have the message.Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

1. `chaine2 = new String()` is redundant. Delete that.
2. You should use the value of `chaine2`, which currently you don't. For example, print it out.

Answer (score 0):

It's the `chaine2 = new String();` You're assigning a new `String()` to `chaine2`, and then immediately discarding it when you reassign it in the next line with `chaine2 = chaine.toLowerCase();`.

Comment: He isn't using the second value, either.

Comment: But using it after the  `toLowerCase()` assignment will make that one go away; the first one will still remain. And if it's not going to be used after `toLowerCase()`, then the entire code becomes meaningless and you shouldn't even bother to compile and run it in the first place. :-)

Comment: Yes, you have described precisely how it is.

Answer (score 0):

`The value of the local variable chaine2 is not used` is a **warning** and not an **error**.

Your IDE is saying that you never use the variable `chaine2`, that is, you neither use it in other operations, nor store it anywhere, nor print it on screen nor anything... Anyway your code will run!

Despite of what is being said in other answers, warnings are very useful notifications about things that **may** lead to errors, so they're very useful while programming, because your IDE will notice issues that you may not notice. So you shouldn't *discard them while learning Java*!

---

**EDIT**: If what you want to do is to get the String "HELLO" in lowercase, don't seek anymore... you got it! The only point is that you have it stored in a avariable `chaine2` but you don't do anything with it...
Just do:

```
System.out.println("Printing chaine2: " + chaine2);
```

And you will see the result printed on the console.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!!and thanks to everybody for the suggestions about the warning!

Answer (score 0):

Learning a specific language, even at the beginning, should not make one programmer forget to carefully design its algorithm. Your algorithm should always be the most optimal as possible.

Moderns IDE help to not forget ;)   => A useless variable? (since in your case, `chaine2` is not used at all after its initialization) => trash it!

Therefore, you should really take care about any warnings throwing by your favorite IDE (or other sources), even for a simple "Hello World" algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

You are setting an object to `chaine2`,

```
chaine2 = new String();
```

but you overwrite it at the next line, so the previously created empty String is not used for anything.

```
chaine2 = chaine.toLowerCase();
```

The compiler finds it odd, since the first line is useless, and warns you in case it is a logic error (although it is a correct program and will compile and run correctly).

Comment: The compiler will keep complaining even if `= new String()` is deleted. OP is not using the value of `chaine2` in any way, either the first or the second one.