# The value of local variable is not used error shows up on "String schedule;"

Tags: java

My String schedule; shows an error "The value of local variable schedule is not used". I am not sure what I did wrong?

```
    int dayofWeek = 6 ;
    
    String schedule; 
    
    switch (dayofWeek) {
    case 1:
        schedule = "Gym in the morning";
        break;
        
    case 2:
        schedule = "Class after work";
        break;
        
    case 3:
        schedule = "Meetings all day";
        break;
        
    case 4:
        schedule = "Work from home";
        break;
        
    case 5:
        schedule = "Game Night after work";
        break;
        
    case 6: case 7:
        schedule = "Free";
        break;
    }
```

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning. You have just assigned a value, but you are not using it somewhere, so your IDE is telling you exactly that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java error "Value of local variable is not used"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062919/java-error-value-of-local-variable-is-not-used)

Comment: @Progman It would normally be a warning, and not an error, but I seem to remember that that is configurable. So it's possible that OP is getting an error.

Comment: @mypetlion Indeed, you can change the severity level of such code checking hints in eclipse. Interesting...